# Java Database Connectivity doesn't work

Tags: java, database, database-connection

I have problem to connect to my Database from my Java Code. I am using MS Access Database. I have created DSR Name and selected appropriate Database for my DSR Name.

```
DSR Name : connectionExample
Operating System : Windows 8 Pro (64 Bit).
Please answer me with full tutorial because I am a newbie.
```

My Java Code for Database Connection Example is :

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class DatabaseConnection {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

                String uName="ABC",uPass="ABC",uEmail="ABC",uDate="ABC",uContactNo="ABC";
           try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
                Connection con =  DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:odbc:connectionExample");
                Statement stmnt = con.createStatement();

                String sql = "insert into UserDetail values ('"+uName + "','"+uPass+"','"+uEmail+"','"+uDate+"','"+uContactNo+"')";
                int cnt = stmnt.executeUpdate(sql);
                   System.out.println("Database Updated.");     
                }
               catch (Exception ex) 
               {
                   System.out.println(ex);
               }
    }

}
```

The Output of my code is :

```
run:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Jdbc-odbc bridge is deprecated in newest java releases

Comment: Use native jdbc driver like this one http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html

Comment: I am using Netbeans 8.0 for programming. I have done nothing manually.

Comment: hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469062/classnotfoundexception-sun-jdbc-odbc-jdbcodbcdriver-in-netbeans-ide

Comment: these are for old jdk versions....I am using jdk 8.

Answer (score 0):

You must add connecter jar file to netbeans project library.

Download jdbc connector jar file.

Copy it to project folder

select project in netbeans choose properties from right click menu.

Select library->add jar file/folder

select jdbc file.
Now your code will work.